# 英語が残っている：ページが見つかりません

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

リンクの例：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/79

信用度が2000以上のユーザーまたはモデレーターのための画像：

> [image: 404]
>
> - Try a Google 検索
> - Browse our recent questions ([Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40540276))
> - Browse our popular tags ([Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40540277))

Comment: 「Google Search (Google 検索)」は[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40287796?q=google)にあるが、「Try a」は[見つからなかった](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40284584?q=try)。

Comment: 「Try a Google検索」は http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1692/8000 で一応`status-plannning`になっています。「Browse～」はTransifexではレビュー済みなのに反映されていませんね・・・。